# how to add ogimage in metadata on nextjs 13?

Tags: next.js

I want to add 'ogimage' in metadata on nextjs 13 to have beautiful social shares. But no information in official docs https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/metadata

Answer (score 6):

The Next.js docs are not in beta anymore and setting up a social image is straightforward.

### Solution

Follow these steps:

1. **Create image files:** Use the `opengraph-image.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)` and `twitter-image.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)` conventions. For example, create `opengraph-image.png` and `twitter-image.png`.
2. **Place the image files:** Put the image files in the respective route segments of your Next.js app. For example, the root image should be in `app/opengraph-image.png`.
3. **Include alt text:** Create text files named `opengraph-image.alt.txt` and `twitter-image.alt.txt` with the desired alt text. Place them in the same route segments as the images.

And that's it, Next.js will populate the metadata for you with the right values.

### Example File Structure

```
├── app
│   ├── page.tsx
│   ├── ...
│   ├── opengraph-image.png
│   ├── twitter-image.png
│   ├── opengraph-image.alt.txt
│   ├── twitter-image.alt.txt
│   └── ...
└── ...
```

I created [this article](https://www.franciscomoretti.com/blog/setting-up-static-og-image-nextjs-app-router) with more details about it and here is the [official documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/metadata/opengraph-image).

Comment: Great explanation, Francisco! I followed what you said but unfortunately it didn't work. In my case the image url was attached to localhost, so it didn't work when got to production -> http://localhost:3000/opengraph-image.png?7b8234c493421156 .
So, I guess we also gotta add the correct url inside the meta tags in nextjs, something that I saw in another nextjs13 repo

Comment: Just found out where the docs talk about that: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/generate-metadata#metadatabase

Comment: Metadata overrides these default paths if you choose to use it. I'm not sure how to troubleshoot your application, please create a new question with more details of your environment.

Answer (score 2):

For NextJS 13, you can find the documentation https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/metadata#opengraph

Otherwise [this article](https://articles.wesionary.team/customize-social-media-preview-of-your-nextjs-website-links-82f6bce035b) can help you..

You still can use the same in the previous version, just put meta in header

Answer (score 1):

Francisco's method is the simplest and most straight forward. However, I had trouble getting it working out of the box when I switched my hosting from Vercel to Netlify.

Moving to Netlify, I had to export a `metadata` object in the root `layout.tsx` file of my project to get og:image working.

```
// layout.tsx
...
export const metadata = {
  title: "Sphere Showcase",
  description:
    "Showcase of Photosphere, 360, and Panorama images from around the world. Upload and share your own!",
  keywords: ["Photosphere", "360 Photo", "Panorama", "World Map"],
  openGraph: {
    images: 'https://photos.sphereshowcase.com/tBJczsgyzUAP3woETDr31.jpg',
  },
};
...
```

I did a further writeup of the steps here [Static Open Graph Image for Next.js App Directory on Netlify](https://thetombomb.com/posts/og-image-nextjs-netlify)